# How to known from registry which Visual Studio Edition is Installed?

Tags: visual-studio

How to known from registry which Visual Studio Edition is Installed?
I mean :

- VS2013 Pro, Premium, Ultimate and
- VS2015 Community, Pro, Enterprise

I read this doc, but it doesn't answer specifically this need.
http://www.mztools.com/articles/2008/MZ2008003.aspx

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just followed the first link from the one you've posted.

VS 2013:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164659.aspx

VS 2015:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164659(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: My bad, didn't see the link and Google search didn't spot these pages!!